Unable to create a build pipeline with yaml in Azure DevOps
I am attempting to build a Pipeline in AzureDevOps (without using the classic editor). I have so far created the following yaml code:
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- adf_publish

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'NewConnectionName'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data Factory-CP/drop/pre-and post-deployment.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data Factory-CP/drop/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    PathtoPublish: 'caplogic-warehouse-dev-df'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

When I validate the code I get the following error:
/my-azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 21, Col: 10): Unexpected value ''

This is must experience with yaml and therefore not sure where to start troubleshooting
Any thoughts on where the error is with the code?

According to your yaml, it seems that you added the AzurePowerShell@5 task to the wrong line, causing the PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task to be destroyed.

It should be:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'NewConnectionName'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data Factory-CP/drop/pre-and post-deployment.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data Factory-CP/drop/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'caplogic-warehouse-dev-df'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'



task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

Your "inputs" param is empty, remove the task if you're not using it or add the required params : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines

Thanks @Arnaud. Watch this space, I will be asking lot more questions

Sure thing, also if you want to publish an artifact, you might want to build it in your pipeline first, since the first steps are just scripts here.
