Unable to deploy DevOps pipeline Error: no such file or directory
I am trying to deploy a Azure DevOps pipeline with the following yaml script
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- adf_publish

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: MyNewPreDeployment'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: NewConnectionName
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data FactoryReName/drop/pre-and post-deployment.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data FactoryReName/drop/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

But I am getting the following error:
##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/_Azure Data FactoryReName/drop/pre-and post-deployment.ps1'


When I try to switch to adf_publish I get the following error


Do I need manually upload to Azure Data Factory CICDCapLogic

The error is telling you the problem: The file doesn't exist at the path where you're telling it to look. Use an inline script step to validate the directory structure.

I strongly suggest not to use spaces in the path

seems missing task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0

It seemed that you were trying to use a YAML pipeline instead of a release pipeline to deploy the ADF entities defined in your ARM json templates.
The path of $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data FactoryReName/drop/pre-and post-deployment.ps1 in your pipeline definition was very likely to be copied from a release pipeline, where the repo Azure Data FactoryReName with artifacts drop were downloaded into the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) during a release.
However, for your YAML pipeline, there was no such download artifacts step as that in your release pipeline. The script file pre-and post-deployment.ps1 and your template files should be probably under some path in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) rather than $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data FactoryReName/drop/, because those files together with the code from the adf_publish branch were checked out into $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) during a build.
With that being said, it is suggested running this command tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to confirm the location of your script file and ARM json templates.
trigger:
- adf_publish

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  displayName: Show file structure of System.DefaultWorkingDirectory during a build

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: MyNewPreDeployment'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(NewConnectionName)
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(some-actual-path-to-script)/pre-and post-deployment.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(some-actual-path-to-templates)/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: '$(NewConnectionName)'
    subscriptionId: '$(AzureSub)'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg-azdatafactory'
    location: 'Southeast Asia'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(some-actual-path-to-templates)/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(some-actual-path-to-templates)/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: '-factoryName "xxxxfactory-instance2" -AzureDataLakeStorage1_accountKey "$(StorageAccountKey)"'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'



Besides, you may also consider using this task AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3, which also works in a YAML pipeline and is typically used for ARM deployment.
For more information on how the variables for pipeline directories are defined, please take reference to the documents below.
Predefined variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn
Classic release and artifacts variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn

Hi @Alvin, this is great. I'm going to see if I can follow what you said. However, you are 100% correct - I was trying to copy from a release pipeline, where the repo Azure Data FactoryReName with artifacts drop were downloaded into the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) during a release.
I will let you know how I get on before I mark your answer

Hi @Patterson, Thanks for the reply. Please feel welcome to reach out. And if possible, please let us know the file structure in your repo or the output of your tree command. Waiting for your good new and always willing to help. Cheers.

I just have one question before I launch into your suggestion. Have you seen my related post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78486434/unable-to-deploy-devops-pipeline-error-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1#comment138370911_78486434
The helper on that posted suggested that I could use the definition copy from the release pipeline, however I think you are suggesting that I can't ... or am I understanding things wrong?

Oops! I meant the following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78484513/unable-to-create-a-build-pipeline-with-yaml-in-azure-devops/78487228#78487228

Hi there, I believe we can use the definition copied from the release pipeline but also need to modify the objects or properties. Taking this case for example, the paths to your script file and json template were probably different between a release pipeline and a build pipeline(YAML). So we can use the same AzurePowerShell task in either release or build pipeline but need to adjust the definition accordingly. :)

For a release pipeline, by default it will download the artifacts files (probably published by an upstream pipeline) into the path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_<So called artifact alias (upstream pipeline name)>/<artifact name (drop)>, where we could find our script file or templates.

For a build pipeline (YAML) on the other hand, by default, it will checkout the code from adf_publish branch of your repo into the path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), rather than $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure Data FactoryReName/drop. You may also notice in the documents that I shared that even the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) is different between a release and build pipeline.

I just wish my managers would just let me use the 'Classic Editor' to create the pipelines - it is soooo much easier with the Classic Editor. I'm finding it really confusing trying to convert from Classic Editor to create a pipeline from scrach with just yaml

Therefore, I believe this difference was the reason that incurred no such file or directory error.

Haha, I can totally understand, the classic editor of a release pipeline is more user-friendly. But don't worry and let's work this issue out.

I am going to start again from scratch.. Can I move this discussion to chat?

By the way, in a YAML pipeline, there is a settings button in grey on top of each pipeline task. You may click on it and enable a tiny UI editor. Not so friendly as the UI of a classic editor, but helps to some extent.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi @Patterson, Good day to you. May I know if the suggestion to modify the path to your ps1 and template file works for you and if the error still exists? Appreciate your efforts and cooperation.

Hi @Alvin, thank you very much for your help yesterday. As you can remember I was pretty stressed out. Are you free to help to today in the chatroom

Hi @Patterson, May I know if you have encountered a new error other than the no such file or directory issue? If yes, please don't hesitate to create a new thread. Sorry I am working in a different time zone and will be off-line soon, but we have experts in EU/US TZ to provide assistance. Thx for taking time to share the update and wish you a nice weekend.
